# JAvascript 180 to -180 rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now when the user clicks on this image, it rotates 180 degrees.
I want to update it to do this: If the user clicks the image, it rotates 180 degrees, but if the user clicks the image again, it rotates back to its original position.

Here's my javascript:

```js
var value = 0
$("#row-1").click(function(){
    value +=180;
    $("#image1").rotate({ animateTo:value});
});
```

HTML:

```html
<th style="text-align:left;" width="20%" id="row-2">
    Company<br>
    <span class="move_right">Name</span> 
    <img src="/images/sort-arrow-up.png" title="Sort by Company Name" alt="Sort by Company Name" class="sort-right move-left" id="image2" />
</th>
```

Comment: flipping -180 in the opposite direction means: flipping 180 in the same direction. so with another click it must keep turning?.  Try it:  click1: 180 degrees clockwise.  click2: -180 degrees counterclockwise.  what does it do?

Comment: But it might turn in the wrong direction ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maintain a separate variable for how much to change the angle and negate it on each click:

```
var value = 0;
var delta = 180;
$("#row-1").click(function(){
    value += delta;
    delta = -delta;
    $("#image1").rotate({ animateTo:value});
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed. :) Don't know why I got two down votes though. @TedHopp

Comment: @PixelReaper - Glad to help. I don't know what the downvotes were for, either.

Comment: Two variables are perhaps a bit unnecessary since you're just flipping between 0 and 180 (`value = value ? 0: 180`)

Comment: @Juhana - True, unless `value` might be changed elsewhere in the code to something other than 0 or 180. If it were my code, I would probably keep two variables to separately represent "current angle" and "amount to rotate"; it would strike me as more maintainable.

Comment: @PixelReaper, I didn't downvote you, but just by way of explanation:  Your code sample was a bit sloppy.  The javascript id's don't match up with the html id's.  And the HTML was just globbed into the question, instead of formatted in a readable manner.  Despite whatever your intentions were, these things make it seem like you didn't put a lot of effort into crafting your question.  A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is always a good place to start for asking questions that are soley comprised of html and javascript.  Glad to see you got an answer that works for you though.

Comment: Thank you for your input, and i'll remember that for next time! :) @KyleMit

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to set your value = -180 at the begening and then every time the user click you do a

```
value = value * -1;
```

This will give : 180, -180, 180, -180 (...) and so on. It's what you want ?

Comment: Um...it happens that +180 and -180 are the same orientation. The value needs to toggle between 0 and +180, not -180 and +180.

Comment: I understood that after ^^ At the beginning, to me when you rotate 180°, you need to rotate -180° to return to the original position ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
var angle = 180;
$("#row-1").toggle(function(){
    value +=angle ;
    $("#image1").rotate({ animateTo:value});
    angle = angle*(-1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but I wanted to get an answer with a fiddle on here.
There is also a dependency on the [jQueryRotate plugin](http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js).

## [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/v6w9q/)

**HTML**:

```html
<table>
    <th id="row-1">
        <p>Company</p>
        <span>Name</span> 
        <img id="image1" src="http://i.imgur.com/wO5gsMy.png"
             title="Sort by Company Name" alt="Sort by Company Name"
             width="25" height="25"/>
    </th>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
var value = 0;
$("#row-1").click(function(){
    value = value ? 0: 180
    $("#image1").rotate({ animateTo:value});
});
```